# Searching JSON recursively for an item with a "selected" attribute

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have the following function, which I believe could be improved with [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming).

```
        function findSelectedInList(list){
        for(var i=0;i<=list.length;i++){                
            var currentItem = list[i];
            if(currentItem.selected === "selected"){
                return currentItem;                    
            }                
            var selectedNode = findSelectedInList(currentItem.children)
            if(selectedNode){
                return selectedNode;
            }                
        }
        return void 0;
    }
```

Here are some sample inputs:

```
    var treeList = [ { "roleName": "User", 
                   "roleId": "role1", 
                   "children": [ { "roleName": "subUser1", "roleId": "role11", "children": [], "selected": "selected" }]
                 }];


    var treeList2 = [ { "roleName": "User", "roleId": "role1", "children": [],"selected":"selected"}];
```

Comment: Something like `return (currentItem.selected === "selected") || findSelectedInList(currentItem.children)` would have fewer variables and "look" more recursive.

Comment: Can only one item in the tree have `selected` set? If not, may any item with `selected` set be returned?

Comment: @Gerrit0 only one item can be selected.
I am writing a utility class for this  https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially, I considered suggesting using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) but then that wouldn't allow breaking out of the loop once a selected item was found.

One approach is to use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (and disregard the return value) with a ternary operator. A variable can be initialized as the first line, then the .some() callback returns the result of setting that variable to either the current item if it is *selected*, otherwise the return value of the recursive call.

```
function findSelectedInList(list) {
  var selected;
  list.some(function(currentItem) {
    return selected = currentItem.selected === "selected" ? currentItem : findSelectedInList(currentItem.children);
  });
  return selected;
}
```

And one could use [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) features like [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [the `let` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)), to condense it slightly:

```
function findSelectedInList(list){
  let selected;
  list.some((currentItem) => selected = currentItem.selected === "selected" ? currentItem : findSelectedInList(currentItem.children));
  return selected;
}
```

To see this demonstrated, expand the snippet below.

```js
var treeList = [{
  "roleName": "User",
  "roleId": "role1",
  "children": [{
    "roleName": "subUser1",
    "roleId": "role11",
    "children": [],
    "selected": "selected"
  }]
}];


var treeList2 = [{
  "roleName": "User",
  "roleId": "role1",
  "children": [],
  "selected": "selected"
}];
var treeList3 = [{
  "roleName": "User",
  "roleId": "role1",
  "children": []
}];

function findSelectedInList(list) {
  var selected;
  list.some(function(currentItem) {
    return selected = currentItem.selected === "selected" ? currentItem : findSelectedInList(currentItem.children);
  });
  return selected;
}
console.log('treeList: ', findSelectedInList(treeList));
console.log('treeList2: ', findSelectedInList(treeList2));
console.log('treeList3: ', findSelectedInList(treeList3));
```

I know it doesn't really cover the *find* or *some* methods, but [these functional JS exercises](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/) are a good thing to go through.

Comment: Cool - perhaps you were notified but I just updated my response to contain more information about other functional methods on the Array prototype.